# Running a test with threadPoolSize > 1 and triggering a @BeforeMethod only once

Tags: concurrency, testng

I want to run a test that uses a singelton resource `MyResource` which can be created and teared down. The resource represents another running program on the same machine which is controlled via command line `Runtime.exec`. The program must be explicitly started and shut down, therefore, calling `MyResource.establishConnection` twice will fail. Failing to call `MyResource.shutDown` will result in the application being open even after the Java program finishes. Now I want to write a test case which checks if the resource can be used after it was started. (Starting and shutting down is tested elsewhere.) The test case I wrote looks like this:

```
private MyResource myResource;

@BeforeMethod(firstTimeOnly = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    myResource = new MyResource();
    myResource.establishConnection();
}

@AfterMethod(lastTimeOnly = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    myResource.shutDown();
}

@Test(invocationCount = 30, threadPoolSize = 5)
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    myResource.use():
}
```

One of the purposes of this test is to check if the resource (`MyResource`) behaves nicely when it is accessed concurrently. However, I now observe that the method annotated with `@BeforeMethod` is called three times - once for every thread - instead of only once. The `firstTimeOnly` seems to not apply to positive`threadPoolSize`s.

Can I fix this? (There are other tests in this test class which are represented by other test methods. This is why I rather do not want to use for example `@BeforeTest` such that the application is restarted in between methods.)

Thanks for any help.

**Update**: More mysteries. This code snippet

```
@BeforeMethod(firstTimeOnly = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Set up");
}

@AfterMethod(lastTimeOnly = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Tear down");
}

@Test(invocationCount = 10)
public void testName() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Running test");
}
```

will print:

> Set up
>
> Running test
>
> Tear down
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test
>
> Running test

So not only is `setUp` called three times as described above, `tearDown` is called too early, even without setting `threadPoolSize`. This is in direct contrast to the javadoc of `@AfterMethod`'s `lastTimeOnly` which says:

> If true and the @Test method that was just run has an invocationCount >
>   1, this AfterMethod will only be invoked once (after the last test invocation).

Comment: I've read this a couple of times, and I still can't understand your final goal.  Do you want your setup to run before each invocation?  Or just once before the test run?

Comment: I basically want to achieve that `setup` is run once before all invocations of `runName` and `tearDown` once after that.

Comment: If you only have 1 test in that class, you could use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`

Comment: And I do not want to use BeforeClass or AfterClass since I have several methods in my actual test case. I want `setUp` and `tearDown` to be called for each method but not for the individual invocations of the same method but only before the first and after the last invocation of a particular method.

Comment: Hm.  I don't see anyway to do it (especially because the way you have written it looks like it should work).  Do you have the latest version of TestNG (6.8.1)?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  Contact Cedric Beust?

Comment: I added an issue already, but I wonder if such a severe bug can make it into a release. I still believe, its some sort of misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source code today, I think this is a bug. I just proposed a fix to it on Git Hub. (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/433)